# Member is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, abstract-class

The code for my app and firebase db connectivity

```
public class pay extends buttons {
String b = String.valueOf(a);

   EditText noteEt, phoneEt;
   Button payp;
   String TAG = "main";

   final int UPI_PAYMENT = 0;

   DatabaseReference reff;
  
   Member member;
 
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay);
      initializeViews();

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    
      ----->  member = new Member();
      reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
```

Member.java is another activity in which looks like this:

```
  public class Member {

    private String dt;
    private String selectionn;
    private String costt;

//constructor
public Member() {
}

//setter and getter
public String getDt() {
    return dt;
}

public void setDt(String dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
}

public String getSelectionn() {
    return selectionn;
}

public void setSelectionn(String selectionn) {
    this.selectionn = selectionn;
}

public String getCostt() {
    return costt;
}

public void setCostt(String costt) {
    this.costt = costt;
 }
}
```

When building the app there's an error saying "Member is abstract; cannot be instantiated" I have marked the error in the first code with an arrow (second last line).

Comment: check your imports ...if you would really use your `public class Member` - not different `Member` class - an error should not appear

Comment: Your `Member` class is not abstract. Are you sure you don't have another abstract `Member` class in your project? Check the right import.

Comment: @AlexMamo i tried renaming the Member class. The error isnt going away. Is there anything else i can try to fix it?

Comment: @Selvin i tried renaming the class but the error wont go away. Are there any other things i could try?